# issue with cocoonjs launcher app on nvidia shield

Tags: android, nvidia, cocoonjs

I'm trying to test a cocoonjs app I made on an Nvidia Shield.  I was able to get to my app from an express server I had running on another pc and that worked fine but I'd like to be able to run the app locally off of an SD card in the shield.

I tried putting my .zip onto a micro sd and putting that into the shield but the launcher dosent show anything in the sd card list. I'm assuming that I have to somehow get the .zip file onto the internal shield sd card itself? Has anyone else done this before? Thanks in advance for the help and I apologize if I'm just missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

The only requirement is that the zip file should be on the root of the SD card.

You can get more infor here:
http://support.ludei.com/hc/en-us/articles/201048463-CocoonJS-launcher-user-guide